# If $F\subseteq K$ are fields, $\alpha \in K$ Prove $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

**If** $F\subseteq K$ are fields, $\alpha \in K$, and $K$ is an extension field of $F$.

**Prove the following are equivalent:**

1. $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$
2. $F(\alpha)=F[\alpha]$
3. $|F(\alpha):F|$ is finite

I'm trying to prove the properties from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_element
 [image]

Edited the question because people voted to close for not understanding what I mean in the original question:

**Intuition:**
I did prove (2.) and (3.) independently, but I'm not sure how to show (1.)

Comment: @Arnaud D. It's the extension field

Comment: Its equivalent to showing $F(\alpha) = F[\alpha]$ and $|F(\alpha) :F|$ is finite.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q(\pi)$, but $\pi$ is not algebraic over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: You need that the extension is finite.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more precise. @ThomasShelby

Comment: So are you trying to prove $(3)\implies (1)$ ?

Comment: @ThomasShelby I want to show that (1), (2), (3) are all equivalent. so I want basically to show that $(1)$ iff $(3)$ in this sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)\implies(2)$
Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, which is irreducible. Take a nonzero element $g(\alpha)\in F[\alpha]$, where $g(x)\in F[x]$. Since $g(\alpha)\ne0$, we have that $f(x)$ doesn't divide $g(x)$; hence a greatest common divisor of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is $1$, so by Bézout's identity there exist $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ such that $f(x)p(x)+g(x)q(x)=1$. Can you conclude $g(\alpha)^{-1}\in F[\alpha]$?

$(2)\implies(3)$
It should be easy to show that $F[\alpha]$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$.

$(3)\implies(1)$
If $|F(\alpha):F|=n$, then $1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^n$ are …

Comment: Hi egreg, from $(3)$ to $(1)$, I can say that $1,\alpha, ..., \alpha^n$ are the linearly dependent elements over $F$ and thus $\alpha$ is algebraic?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS No, they aren't *all* the elements; but they're $n+1$ elements in a vector space of dimension $n$, so they're linearly dependent. What does this give?

Comment: Can I conclude from that, that there exists some non-zero polynomial $g(x)$ with coefficients in $K$ such that $g(a) = 0$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Yes: the elements are linearly dependent, so there are $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_n\in F$, not all zero, such that $c_0+c_1\alpha+\dots+c_n\alpha^n=0$, so $\alpha$ is a root of $c_0+c_1x+\dots+c_nx^n\in F[x]$.

Comment: I see, thank you. (:

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$(3)\implies (1)$ : Suppose degree of $\alpha$ over $F$ is $n$, that is, $[F(\alpha):F]=n$. Then consider these $n+1$ elements: $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots \alpha^n$, which are linearly dependent over $F$.

$(1)\implies (3)$ : If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, then $F(\alpha)\cong\dfrac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$, where $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. Dimension of $\dfrac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$ as a vector space over $F$ is same as the degree of $p(x)$.